# Pesquisa recusada ao registrar nome do Host do DigitalOcean no registro.br

Tags: dns

Estou tentando configurar minha *droplet* com o domínio que comprei no [registro.br](https://registro.br/) seguindo o tutorial da [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-host-name-with-digitalocean).

No segundo passo do tutorial diz que tenho que trocar os servidores de domínio do **registro.br** para os do **digitalocean**.

Estou tentando fazer isso indo no meu domínio na seção **DNS** e clicando na opção **ALTERAR SERVIDORES DNS**

Porém quando faço isso sou apresentado com o seguinte erro ao clicar em **SALVAR DADOS**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe onde estou errando? Estou fazendo isso no local correto?

Comment: tentou trocar de navegador ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consegui resolver esse problema executando o passo **três** do [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-host-name-with-digitalocean) antes do **dois**.

Parece que o *registro.br* antes de alterar o servidor DNS faz uma consulta ao novo servidor para saber se ele possui registro do seu domínio, por isso estava dando `Pesquisa recusada`. Após registrar meu domínio no Digital Ocean o erro desapareceu.

Answer (score 0):

Após adicionar o domínio no painel de controle cloud.digitalocean.com/networking/domains, é preciso atribuir uma Droplet para ele, assim ele criará uma quarta entrada além dos 3 NSs.

Para isso, clique em Projects -> Nome do Seu Projeto -> Droplet -> Menu Contextual (...) -> Add Domain.

Resumindo: não basta adicionar o domínio no painel da Digital Ocean, é preciso linkar esse domínio com um projeto/app/droplet